# valueForKeyPath with nested JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, key-value, alamofire

I have a problem in using valueForKeyPath, here the way I get the dataVersion value and it's works perfectly:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.amazon.fr/s", parameters:parameters)
   .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) -> Void in

       let priceResult: String? = JSON?.valueForKeyPath("reponseMetadata.dataVersion") as String?
       println(priceResult)

 }
```

But when I try to access the url value like this, it's fail

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.amazon.fr/s", parameters:parameters)
   .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) -> Void in

       let priceResult: String? = JSON?.valueForKeyPath("preloadImages.images.url") as String?
       println(priceResult)

 }
```

Here my Json :

```
{
    responseMetadata: {
      dataVersion: "v0.1"
    },
    preloadImages: {
      images: [
          {
              url: "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51K4P7REBKL._SL500_AC_.jpg"
          }
      ]
    }
}
```

I new in IOs so any help would be most welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preloadImages.images` is an array of objects (Array of Dictionary in swift-speak) so your `valueForKeyPath` won't work.  Unfortunately, there isn't any way to index an array through valueForKeyPath, so you'll have to get it less directly:

```
let string = "{ \"responseMetadata\": { \"dataVersion\": \"v0.1\" }, \"preloadImages\": { \"images\": [ { \"url\": \"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51K4P7REBKL._SL500_AC_.jpg\" } ] } }"
var error : NSError?
let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
if let json: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .allZeros, error: &error) {
    if let images = json.valueForKeyPath("preloadImages.images") as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>> {
        let url = images[0]["url"]

        println("url = \(url)")
    }
} else {
    println("json failed: \(error)")
}
```

Note that your JSON also isn't valid as shown since the object keys aren't quoted, I assume you're dumping the JSON variable using println instead of showing the actual JSON data.